# Python Regex to extract addresses and travel time from a sentence?

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a regex to parse addresses and time from a sentence. The different sentence variable are:

> 1. I want to go from Cosmos Station to 525 Greenlane highway.
> 2. I want to go from Cosmos Station to 525 Greenlane highway tomorrow at 8am.
> 3. I want to go from Cosmos Station to 525 Greenlane highway at 8am.

I am looking to approach this problem in a simple way, get a text between from and to and assume it’s a origin and so on.

```
from(.*)to(*.)
```

Is this the right way to go? I am looking to extract origin, destination and time. The expected out is:

```
Origin = cosmos station
Destination = 525 Greenlane Highway
remaining_string = none if sentences ends at destination
remaining_string = text after destination
```

Comment: `(*.)` is certainly wrong.

Comment: The issue here is that you need to define some rules to apply. For instance `525 Greenlane highway` seems to be the  the destination in the second example. How do you differenciate destination and time?

Comment: Try `/from (.*) to (.*) at (.*)`? Maybe you can hardcode "tomorrow" and other special words that can appear before "at", but in general this is a problem that is too hard for regular expressions, you need some kind of entity detection/semantic parsing/....

Comment: please specify your expected output.

Comment: Added expected output

Comment: @Joyfulgrind: A starting point could be https://regex101.com/r/gE97EF/1

Comment: Are you by chance going to try and parse more sentence structures that express the same thing? If so, you may want to look into Phrase Chunking.

Answer (score 0):

```
from\s(?P<Origin>[\d\w\s]*?)\sto\s(?P<Dest>[\d\w\s]*?)(?:$|(?P<Time>\b(?:tomorrow|at)\b.*))
```

You can take a look at my solution [in a live online demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oUEVi6/2).

There are three named capture groups, one for each of your target variables.

You'll notice in the Time capture group that I have `(tomorrow|at)` which is being used to match the time starting word of the time substring.

While this works for your specific questions, this will have to be expanded for all of the other time values that could possible be checked against.

It's hard to make a regex that will capture all of the edge cases if we don't know what assumptions that we can, or can't, make, so feel free to post the full set of expected input.

Answer (score 0):

This work for the given sample:

```
import re

string = """
I want to go from Cosmos Station to 525 Greenlane highway.
I want to go from Cosmos Station to 525 Greenlane highway tomorrow at 8am.
I want to go from Cosmos Station to 525 Greenlane highway at 8am
"""
# to make the pattern a little readable
# in your example time separator are either at or tomorrow at you can add more
at_separators = {'at': '(?:(?:tomorrow at)|(?:at))'}
# after to we capture all string if there is no at separator after it
# if there is second group will capture the string between too and at separator
pattern = 'from\s(.+?)\sto\s(.+?(?=\s{at})|.+(?!{at}\s))(?:\s{at}(.+))?'.format(**at_separators)
pattern = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.MULTILINE)
# no you hust need to clean the result to clean '.' and noises because doing this
# in the pattern will make it a unreadable.
print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

Output:

```
[('Cosmos Station', '525 Greenlane highway.', ''), ('Cosmos Station', '525 Greenlane highway', ' 8am.'), ('Cosmos Station', '525 Greenlane highway', ' 8am')]
```

As you can see in the first group the Third position is empty string because there is not Time. The key was positive lookahead `.+?(?=\s{at})` witch will not consume the time part but it will be return by `(?:\s{at}(.+))?`.